# Orders are not displaying in admin on opencart

Tags: admin, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2. Based on the objective of my project i have changed few coding at order module and the order also stored successfully at the database oc_order table.My question is the orders are not displaying on the admin/sales/order page. I hope someone will help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your order goes successfully.Your order detail must should be in these table. oc_order,oc_order_option,oc_order_product with your order id. If any problem persist still let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ravi Kumar. I have checked these tables but at oc_order_option has no data.

Comment: thats why your order are not displaying in admin order page. try to fix your  by looking at default order function of opencart

Comment: I checked the oc_order table. And status for the order is zero.. is that a problem @Ravi Kumar

Comment: Cart Procedure goes from this function step wise  1. $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

2. $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
3.  $product_options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->post['product_id']);
4. $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);  Check these functions you can find solution